# Black screen when popping context

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Configurações")),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: usernameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Nome de usuário",
                      hintText: "Mudar seu nome de usuário"),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: heightController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Altura", hintText: "Mudar sua altura"),
                ),
              ),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: const Text("Notifications"),
                  value: hasPushNotificationOn,
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                        hasPushNotificationOn = value;
                      })),
              SwitchListTile(
                title: const Text("Dark mode"),
                value: isDarkMode,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  isDarkMode = value;
                }),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      await storage.setDouble(
                          K_HEIGHT, double.parse(heightController.text));
                    } catch (e) {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text("Erro"),
                          content: const Text("Altura inválida"),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                child: const Text("Ok"))
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    await storage.setString(
                        K_USERNAME, usernameController.text);
                    await storage.setBool(K_DARK_MODE, isDarkMode);
                    await storage.setBool(
                        K_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, hasPushNotificationOn);
                    Navigator.pop(context);

                    setState(() {
                      username = usernameController.text;
                      height = double.tryParse(heightController.text);
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.save_as_rounded))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

This leads to the initial code:

```
ListTile(
            title: const Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.settings),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text("Configurações"),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const SettingsPage(),
                  ));
            },
          ),
```

This is supposed to be a super simple configuration menu. I get a total black screen when I click on the save icon or when I get an error at this try catch statement, it doesnt display the dialog at all.

Is it a problem with the navigator.pop? Why does it happen?

Also, I tried getting the context out of the async function by declaring a variable before the onPressed() inside the floatingButton but it also didnt work.

Comment: do you have a screen before this? how do you open this screen? if you are on this screen and there is no screen/widget in the stack and you pop, you will get a black screen.

Comment: I am at the main page, I open this through a menu drawer, so it surely has another screen behind it

Comment: can you show the code u use to show/open this screen? add in your question

Comment: there, it's an option inside a sidebar menu

Comment: Ah pushReplacement, replaces the current route in the stack. if you are wanting to pop the settings page to return here, you should do push instead, so that pop pops the settings from the view stack. or if you want to use pushReplacement you would need to the same on the settings to return to the page you came from.

Comment: but navigator.pop(context) should still work inside the dialog right? I dont get it why it doesnt appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the main page

And if you use:

```
pushReplacement
```

This will replace your current route with the new one, so you can't go back.

Use `push` instead.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html

About the question why your `pop` doesn't work on your dialog it's because you are using the wrong context.

In this part of the code.

```
 showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text("Erro"),
                          content: const Text("Altura inválida"),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                child: const Text("Ok"))
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
```

You are not showing the "context" generated from the Dialog.

```
builder: (_)
```

Just change to this

```
builder: (context)
```

Comment: but navigator.pop(context) should still work inside the dialog right? I dont get it why it doesnt appears